# WPF DataGrid RowHeader MouseEnter MouseEventHandler

Tags: wpf, datagrid, mouseover, datagridrowheader

I have datagrid and it's loaded event I would like to create event handler for Mouse Enter and Mouse Leave.

I was able to do it for Datagrid Column header but I dont know how to do it for Row.

Here is code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader = DataGridHelper.GetColumnHeader(this, i);
            if (columnHeader != null)
            {
                columnHeader.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(ColumnHeader_MouseEnter);
                columnHeader.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(ColumnHeader_MouseLeave);
            }
        }
```

Pls Help me.
Thanks
Dee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
  <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="MyMouseEnterHandler"/>
  <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="MyMouseLeaveHandler"/>
</Style>
```

You should be able to do the same for the column headers and get rid of the code behind.

Comment: I know but, in my case I have to create handler from code only, while data-grid row loaded. everything from code behind